# Клавиатура в android

Tags: android, java

Привет всем. При клике на EditText открывается клавиатура, чтобы ввести туда что-либо. Но мне не хватает там кнопочки "Done". Есть ли в андроид возможность использовать другие виды клавиатур? И по клике на "Done" выполнять какое-либо событие. Спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

не это ли ищите [keyboard-input](https://developer.android.com/training/keyboard-input/style.html)?

Answer (score 0):

> При клике на EditText открывается клавиатура, чтобы ввести туда что-либо. Но мне не хватает там кнопочки "Done".

Задайте для *EditText* атрибут *android:imeOptions* со значением *actionDone*. Другие возможные значения можно посмотреть в документации.

> И по клике на "Done" выполнять какое-либо событие.

Установите [*OnEditorActionListener*](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.OnEditorActionListener.html) для вашего *EditText* вызовом *setOnEditorActionListener*. В нём обрабатывайте интересующие вас события.

Comment: Почему-то не появляется кнопка. Из-за чего это может быть? Я не указал android:inputType. Возможно из-за этого. Спасибо.

Comment: Если не появляется после указания imeOptions, то, значит, текущая клавиатура не поддерживает это. Часто этим грешат стоковые клавиатуры HTC. В любом случае, насколько я помню, imeOptions - это рекомендация клавиатуре, а не строгое требование, так что отдельные вендоры вполне себе могут на это дело забить.

Comment: Я не указал android:inputType. Возможно из-за этого. Теперь все отлично. Спасибо. И еще вопрос. При создании активити я сделал editText в фокусе, но клавиатура не появляется. Только при клике на EditText. Как это можно сделать?

Comment: Посмотрите в манифесте параметры самого Activity. Там есть варианты появления клавиатуры.

Comment: Как вам выше верно посоветовали, смотрите атрибут *android:windowSoftInputMode* тега *activity* в AndroidManifest.xml.